# Getting Error (PermissionError: [WinError 5] Access is denied) when Execute below code

Tags: python, boto3

```
import boto3

_BUCKET_NAME = 'Bucket_Name'
_PREFIX = 'data/'

ACCESS_KEY='*********************'
SECRET_KEY='**************************'

client = boto3.client('s3', aws_access_key_id=ACCESS_KEY,
                            aws_secret_access_key=SECRET_KEY)

def ListFiles(client):
    """List files in specific S3 URL"""
    response = client.list_objects(Bucket=_BUCKET_NAME, Prefix=_PREFIX)
    for content in response.get('Contents', []):
        yield content.get('Key')

file_list = ListFiles(client)
for file in file_list:
client.download_file('Bucket_Name',file,'C:/Users/UserName/Desktop/folder/')
```

> Traceback (most recent call last):
>
> File "", line 21, in 
>       client.download_file('Bucket_Name',file,'C:/Users/User/Desktop/folder')
>
> File
>   "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\boto3\s3\inject.py", line
>   172, in download_file
>       extra_args=ExtraArgs, callback=Callback)
>
> File
>   "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\boto3\s3\transfer.py",
>   line 307, in download_file
>       future.result()
>
> File
>   "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\s3transfer\futures.py",
>   line 106, in result
>       return self._coordinator.result()
>
> File
>   "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\s3transfer\futures.py",
>   line 265, in result
>       raise self._exception
>
> File
>   "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\s3transfer\tasks.py", line
>   126, in **call**
>       return self._execute_main(kwargs)
>
> File
>   "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\s3transfer\tasks.py", line
>   150, in _execute_main
>       return_value = self._main(**kwargs)
>
> File
>   "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\s3transfer\download.py",
>   line 603, in _main
>       osutil.rename_file(fileobj.name, final_filename)
>
> File
>   "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\s3transfer\utils.py", line
>   271, in rename_file
>       rename_file(current_filename, new_filename)
>
> File
>   "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\s3transfer\compat.py",
>   line 25, in rename_file
>       os.remove(new_filename)
>
> PermissionError: [WinError 5] Access is denied:
>   'C:/Users/User/Desktop/folder'

Comment: Please format your code and add more details about what you are trying to accomplish.

Comment: now. you may check

Answer (score 9):

Permission error message is misleading. The download_file expects a target file name parameter and not a folder

```
client.download_file('Bucket_Name',object_key,'C:\\temp\\file_name.txt')
```

Comment: I was getting this even while running aws cli commands. You saved me here totally!!

Answer (score 0):

You are missing a forward slash at the end of your path. Python thinks it is a file instead of a folder and throws an error. Replace last line

```
client.download_file('Bucket_Name',file,'C:/Users/UserName/Desktop/folder')
```

with:

```
client.download_file('Bucket_Name',file,'C:/Users/UserName/Desktop/folder/')
```

Comment: You did change the "username" part to your actual username, right?